# Docker fails to restart container on boot when using a mounted cifs volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mount, systemctl, cifs

I have a cifs network share, which I have mounted in a docker container. The docker container has 'restart: always'. Upon reboot, the docker container attempts to start up before the cifs volume starts, resulting in the docker container not starting. I am able to start the docker container manually after boot. The cifs share is not mounted on my host, it is just shared by a remote server.

If possible, I'd like to modify the docker-compose file such that this no longer becomes an issue, and if not, I'd like to modify the systemctl unit file to start the correct mount service before docker.

Here is my docker compose:

```
version: "3"
services:
runner:
  platform: linux/arm64
  build:
    context: ./
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
  restart: always
  volumes:
    - type: volume
      source: data
      target: /mnt/data
      read_only: true
  environment:
    - "ORGANIZATION=${ORGANIZATION}"
    - "REPOSITORY=${REPOSITORY}"
    - "ACCESS_TOKEN=${ACCESS_TOKEN}"
    - "LABELS=${LABELS}"
  deploy:
    replicas: 1
    resources:
      limits:
        cpus: "6"
        memory: 20G
      reservations:
        cpus: "0.25"
        memory: 128M
        devices:
          - driver: nvidia
            capabilities: [gpu]
volumes:
  data:
    driver: local
      driver_opts:
        type: cifs
        device: "//10.0.253.30/ml"
        o: "username=xxxx,password=xxxx,uid=1000,gid=1000"
```

This is the output of `journalctl -u docker.service`:

```
Nov 21 14:44:09 ias-desktop systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
Nov 21 14:44:09 ias-desktop dockerd[1559]: time="2023-11-21T14:44:09.826375272+11:00" level=info msg="Starting up"
Nov 21 14:44:09 ias-desktop dockerd[1559]: time="2023-11-21T14:44:09.827374184+11:00" level=info msg="detected 127.0.0.53 nameserver, assuming systemd-resolved, so using resolv.conf: /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf"
Nov 21 14:44:09 ias-desktop dockerd[1559]: time="2023-11-21T14:44:09.919450088+11:00" level=info msg="[graphdriver] using prior storage driver: overlay2"
Nov 21 14:44:10 ias-desktop dockerd[1559]: time="2023-11-21T14:44:10.160781736+11:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
Nov 21 14:44:10 ias-desktop dockerd[1559]: time="2023-11-21T14:44:10.425001800+11:00" level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip can be used to set a preferred IP address"
Nov 21 14:44:10 ias-desktop dockerd[1559]: time="2023-11-21T14:44:10.619689928+11:00" level=info msg="No non-localhost DNS nameservers are left in resolv.conf. Using default external servers: [nameserver 8.8.8.8 nameserver 8.8.4.4]"
Nov 21 14:44:10 ias-desktop dockerd[1559]: time="2023-11-21T14:44:10.619763912+11:00" level=info msg="IPv6 enabled; Adding default IPv6 external servers: [nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8888 nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8844]"
Nov 21 14:44:10 ias-desktop dockerd[1559]: time="2023-11-21T14:44:10.869163080+11:00" level=error msg="failed to start container" container=c85a69c2c836f3f8e8cc5d6b5ff27cd81241bdc5016d412ddfa7eb0ace1d10db error="error while mounting volume '/var/lib/docker/volumes/test-orin_data/_data': failed to mount local volume: mount //10.0.253.30/ml:/var/lib/docker/volumes/test-orin_data/_data, data: username=orin,password=********,uid=1000,gid=1000: network is unreachable"
Nov 21 14:44:10 ias-desktop dockerd[1559]: time="2023-11-21T14:44:10.869886600+11:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
Nov 21 14:44:10 ias-desktop dockerd[1559]: time="2023-11-21T14:44:10.952849288+11:00" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit="24.0.5-0ubuntu1~20.04.1" graphdriver=overlay2 version=24.0.5
Nov 21 14:44:10 ias-desktop dockerd[1559]: time="2023-11-21T14:44:10.954084712+11:00" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
Nov 21 14:44:11 ias-desktop dockerd[1559]: time="2023-11-21T14:44:11.137733576+11:00" level=info msg="API listen on /run/docker.sock"
Nov 21 14:44:11 ias-desktop systemd[1]: Started Docker Application Container Engine.
```

This is my latest attempt to fix the issue by creating, then modifying, /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/override.conf.

```
[Unit]
Requires=remote-fs.target network.target network-online.target
After=remote-fs.target network.target network-online.target
```

This seems to be a solution for nfs mounts, but I am using a cifs mount:
https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/25584